# The proper word

Tags: proper-nouns

Q1. Which one is proper here, "Beside" or "Besides?"
Q2. "Beside" and "Besides are never interchangeable here?

"...Numerous biodiversity experiments have been conducted since Elton’s time and several mechanisms have been proposed to explain the often observed negative relationship between diversity and invasibility.
**Beside/Besides** the decreased chance of empty ecological niches but the increased probability of competitors that prevent invasion success, diverse communities are assumed to use resources more completely and, therefore, limit the ability of invaders to establish..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct word is "besides", in this sense:
[Merriam-Webster "besides"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/besides) 
preposition 2. : together with
*a decision that, besides being practical, is morally right*

The sentence is confusing because of the word "but", which would make more sense as "and":

> Besides the decreased chance of empty ecological niches **and** the increased probability of competitors that prevent invasion success,...

The paper can be seen here:
[Animal Ecosystems etc.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2565839/pdf/pone.0003489.pdf)
It is from a German university, and it may be an imperfect translation.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say thanks. I've just noticed that while going over my questions. I'd like to say "Thank you for your kind answer", though it is so late. :)